# Can't auto install .msi file which is extra from CAB file download from website

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-installer, setup.exe, wix3.11

I can't auto install .msi file which is extra from CAB file. I made a DLL file and   package it into MSI file. THis MSI file was created by  WIX. Then I wrapper this MSI file into CAB file. When user download cab file using IE browser, it cannot be install this msi. How can i fix it? Or How can I create setp.exe file using WIX.

Comment: Anyone help on this?

Comment: More information - what happens when you do the install? Error messages? Rollback? How are you extracting the MSI file from the CAB file? The problem is not the tool you are using to create the MSI, it's related to your use of the MSI and the CAB file. Even if you create a setup.exe with WiX it will still want to run an MSI file.

Comment: Thanks, PhilDW. I used the WIX to create the .exe file. and I can install the exe file. But the cab file didnt update the local version when i changed the INF file version in CAB file. I don't know why.